# Google cloud credentials, would changing package name or sha-1 certificate fingerprint require re-verification

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-fit

this is a quite simple question, but would changing app bundle identifier, or sha-1 fingerprint on google cloud platform require submitting app for verification again? Currently app uses one restricted scope. As for application functionality nothing will change, except bundle identifier and version number. Appreciate any help, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You will only need to re-verify your app If you edit any of the details on your OAuth consent screen. Such as the project's icon, display name, homepage or privacy policy URL, or approved domains.

For more information about this topic, see [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en).